# Compute gcd$(24, 54 + 24^{7})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

> Compute $\gcd(24, 54 + 24^{7})$.

My attempt:

Euclidean algorithm:

$ a = bq + r$

$ 54 + 24^{7} = 24.24^{6} + 54$

In this case my $ \ r  = 54 \gt 24 = b$. However, in Euclidean's algorithm $ \ 0 \le r < b$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about subtracting off some more multiples of $24$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown gcd$(24, 54 + 24^{7}) = $ gcd$(24, 54 + 24^{7} - 24^{6}.24)$ = gcd$(24,54)$. Do you mean like this ?

Comment: That's more like it!

Comment: I see. Can we still use Euclidean's algorithm?

Comment: That _is_ the Euclidean algorithm. Or at least one step of it.

Answer (score 1):

$24^7+54=24.(24^6+2)+6$.

$24=6.4+0$.

So $\gcd(24^7+54,24)=\gcd(24,6)=\gcd(6,0)=6$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $24^7$ divided by $24$, we see that $\gcd(24,54+24^7)=\gcd(24,54)=6.$